# lim inf inequality question.

Tags: inequality

I'm reading a book and just can't understand why the marked inequality is true.

Could someone clarify ?

Note: the $f_j$s are just functions $f_j:X \to [-\infty,+\infty]$ where $X$ is a metric space.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $d(x,y) <\epsilon$ then $t <f_j(y)\leq f_j(y)+\lambda d(x,y)^{p}$. If $d(x,y) \geq \epsilon$ then $t \leq \lambda\epsilon ^{p} \leq \lambda d(x,y)^{p}\leq f_j(y)+\lambda d(x,y)^{p}$. Hence in all cases $t <f_j(y)+\lambda d(x,y)^{p}$.

Comment: can you explain the first sentence? "if $d(x,y)\lt \epsilon$ then $t\lt f_j(y) \le f_j(y) + \lambda d(x,y)^p$ , why are you assuming $\lambda d(x,y)^p \ge 0 $ ?

Comment: @infinity In the definition of $s$  the supremum is taken over $\lambda \geq 0$.

Comment: Right.. thanks!